# Ubuntu Window Size in Hyper-V

Tags: 18.04, hyper-v

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Windows 10 machine using Hyper-V Manager version 10.0.19041.1.
The size of the Ubuntu window is always the same, it can't be maximized or re-sized. Is there
a way to get this enabled? The window size is too small.

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit `/etc/default/grub`.

Please have a look at

https://arcanecode.com/2020/12/28/adjust-the-screen-resolution-of-an-ubuntu-hyper-v-virtual-machine/

Comment: Good start.  Could you improve your answer by giving more detail on the GRUB settings to be edited?  This way, your aznswer remains valid even if the link disappears.  This is the recommandation on this site.